# UriMatcher handing back wrong value

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I have two Uris.  Suppose they are:

```
content://myprovider/messages
content://myprovider/messages/#
```

In my extended ContentProvider I have declared the following:

```
    private static final int MESSAGES = 1;
    private static final int MESSAGES_ID = 2;

    private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher;

    static {
        sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        sUriMatcher.addURI("myprovider", "messages", MESSAGES);
        sUriMatcher.addURI("myprovider", "messages/#", MESSAGES_ID);
    }
```

When I use the...

```
content://myprovider/messages/#
```

...Uri when calling any ContentProvider method, say insert, and my ContentProvider method does a...

```
sUriMatcher.match(uri)
```

...and I get back 1 (MESSAGES).

Why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `MESSAGES_ID`, the uri has to be written like `content://myprovider/messages/12345` or you have to add a pattern for `MESSAGES_ID` like:

```
sUriMatcher.addURI("myprovider", "messages/*", MESSAGES_ID);
```